# How can I fail on first syntax error in a python ANTLR generated parser while keeping the error message?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm using the `antlr.error.ErrorStrategy.BailErrorStrategy` for my parser. Sometimes (depending on the input) it will report a human readable version of the syntax error (like `line 2:3: mismatched input XXX expecting YYY`) and sometimes it won't (just an exception with no `line 2:3:  some message`):

```
import pytest
import json
import sys
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.error.ErrorStrategy import DefaultErrorStrategy, BailErrorStrategy

from sqliteparser.SQLiteLexer import SQLiteLexer
from sqliteparser.SQLiteParser import SQLiteParser


def test_create_table():
    input_stream = InputStream("\nCREATE OR REPLACE VIEW APPDELETIONS as (\n")
    lexer = SQLiteLexer(input_stream)
    def recover(self,re):
        raise re
    lexer.recover = recover
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = SQLiteParser(stream)
    parser._errHandler = BailErrorStrategy()
    tree = parser.parse()
```

Is there a way to get the an error strategy that always reports a textual representation of the  syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to subclass `BailErrorStrategy` and call `reportError`:

```
class MyErrorStrategy(BailErrorStrategy):
    def recover(self, recognizer:Parser, e:RecognitionException):
        recognizer._errHandler.reportError(recognizer,e)
        super().recover(recognizer,e)
```

then simply call `parser._errHandler = MyErrorStrategy()`.

This will ensure that the actual syntax error (e.g. `line 2:18 mismatched input 'VIEW' expecting K_TABLE`)  will be printed to the console. You can add other error listeners via `parser.addErrorListener(...)`.