# ANTLR4 Python in Unittest: how to abort on any error

Tags: python, antlr4, python-unittest

I want to test my lexer/parser in a Python Unittest. For that purpose I'd like antlr to fail with an Exception everytime anything is out of order. What is the most elegant way to achieve this?

I have read the [ANTLR Mega Tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/#testing-with-python), there they write an `ErrorListener` which overrides `syntaxError()` to save the last offending symbol and then in the end, they check if any offending symbol was encountered.

I saw that there are different [ErrorStrategy](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Python3/src/antlr4/error/ErrorStrategy.py) classes and `BailErrorStrategy` sounds like this is what I need. But then I read [How can I fail on first syntax error in a python ANTLR generated parser while keeping the error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263601/how-can-i-fail-on-first-syntax-error-in-a-python-antlr-generated-parser-while-ke) which says this strategy doesn't alway throw an Exception.

My best idea so far is to throw an Exception in `ErrorListener.syntxError()`:

```py
import unittest
from antlr4 import *
from antlr.myLexer import myLexer
from antlr.myParser import myParser
from antlr4.error.ErrorListener import ErrorListener


class MyErrorListener(ErrorListener):
    def syntaxError(self, recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, e):
        raise Exception("ERROR: when parsing line %d column %d: %s\n" % \
                        (line, column, msg))


class TestMyParser(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_with_testfile(self):
        error_listener = MyErrorListener()
        input_stream = FileStream("testfile")
        lexer = myLexer(input_stream)
        lexer.removeErrorListeners()
        lexer.addErrorListener(error_listener)
        stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
        parser = myParser(stream)
        parser.removeErrorListeners()
        parser.addErrorListener(error_listener)
        tree = parser.startrule()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option you have is the `BailErrorStategy`. It uses an exception which is not catched anywhere in the ANTLR4 runtime and hence that bubbles up to your own code directly.

If you use a normal error handler/default strategy it will always try to recover from syntax errors to allow continuing the parse run.

But even with the `BailErrorStrategy` in place you can have an error listener to get the first (and only) error that came up. For the error messages I recommend attaching your own error listener class to produce your own version of the error message like I did [in this C++ code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/modules/db.mysql.parser/src/mysql_parser_module.cpp#L398)